# Login pages fail - Webserver Stress Tool

Tags: jmeter, webserver, performance-testing, load-testing, stress-testing

I've been using a tool from passler called **[Webserver Stress Tool](https://www.paessler.com/tools/webstress)** to do stress tests to webservers.

The problem is, the tool is obsolete since 2012 but my company still wants to use it. (even though JMeter is available)

I've been having a few problems when automating through Login pages, when specifying the URL pattern the simulated users must follow (using "URL recorder" option in the tool), if there is a Login page in the sequence it always fails.

The information online is so little and im having some difficulties finding something useful that could help me. Even the Tool KB cant enlighten me about this...

Even if you dont know the tool in question could you give me some pointers or guesses about what can be happening? (so i could do some search about it)

Thank you

Comment: Use Fiddler (or similar) to record the requests and responses when logging in manually and when the tool tries to login. Compare the two recordings.

Comment: Did you try if JMeter can replay your recorded scenario without errors?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give you anything useful when not knowing the structure of your testplan and the solution you're trying to test. A few things that come into my mind;

- Cookie handling ?
- Are you using follow-redirects ?
- Did you test if the users are actually able to login or not ?

etc.